# ExecutorService and Future are blocking the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, lwjgl, future, executorservice

I'm developing a game in java and I implemented a multi-threading system to perform a terrain generation which is a repetitive task (~10-20 tasks, each taking ~10-20ms, in one frame). The goal is to:

- Divide the time the tasks are taking, because I don't want my player to have a freeze whenever terrain is generating.
- Don't wait for the terrains to generate. For example, if I am moving and the terrains in front of me are still generating, I don't want the main thread to wait until the terrains are generated, I want the game to continue running until the future is done and the info is retrieved to render the terrain.

The first goal is reached, the terrains are relatively fast to generate, but the main thread is blocked whenever I generate terrains, causing a freeze when generating.

Here is my code:

```
//method called each frame
private void checkForFutures(List<Future<SomeClass>> terrainsInCreation) {
        System.out.println("NEW CHECK"); 
        try
        {
            List<Future<SomeClass>> futuresToRemove = new ArrayList<Future<SomeClass>>();
            for(Future<SomeClass> future:terrainsInCreation) {
                if(future.isDone()) {
                    float time = DisplayManager.getCurrentTime();
                    try {
                        SomeClass t = future.get();
                        // Some instructions (EDIT:)
                        Key key = new Key(t.terrain.getChunkX(),t.terrain.getChunkZ());
                        t.terrain.generateTerrain(loader, t.vertices, t.indices,t.colors, t.normals); // Guilty line !

                        terrains.put(key, t.terrain);
                        terrainsToRender.add(t.terrain);
                        futuresToRemove.add(future);
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Thread.sleep(1000000);
                    }
                    System.out.println("future done, took: " + (DisplayManager.getCurrentTime()-time)); 
// The first future is always taking ~ 100-200ms, which is the time it takes to generate all the terrains
// roughly divided by 4, which is the numbers of core I have
                }
            }
            terrainsInCreation.removeAll(futuresToRemove);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            System.err.println("BIG PROBLEM ON TERRAIN MANAGER");          
        }
    }

//method called when I have terrains to generate
    private void generate(List<Callable<SomeClass>> terrainsToCreate) {

        for(int i = 0; i < terrainsToCreate.size();i++) {
            terrainsInCreation.add(executor.submit(terrainsToCreate.get(i)));
        } 
    }
```

Here is the output of the print:

```
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
future done, took: 165.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 0.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 2.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 0.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 0.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 2.0
future done, took: 0.0
future done, took: 1.0
future done, took: 2.0
future done, took: 2.0
future done, took: 0.0
future done, took: 0.0
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
NEW CHECK
```

As you can see I'm using the future.isDone() method, but if it finds a done future, it still blocks when calling future.get(), the proof is the print I'm doing at the end which give a large time for the first future, and then ~1ms for each future to retrieve the info which is normal behavior.

My question is how to literally execute the tasks in parallel, and retrieve the results when finished but without blocking the main thread at all? (The not finished futures shouldn't be awaited)

**Edit**

I isolated the script in a minimal reproducible project and the issue was gone, the guilty line is one of the `//Some instructions` , so first I added these lines to the code above, and second I'll keep investigating and update the post.

I finally isolated the one line that freezes the whole process:

```
int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
```

So basically, after getting the future I call `terrain.generate` which creates a model from the vertices, normal, colors etc infos. To create the model, I first create a vao, and the first step to create this vao is this line and the first time it gets created in this frame, it freezes until every other futures are done this is insane!

I have to say that I'm definitely lost and I don't know a single thing to do.

Comment: I think terrainsInCreation.add() is blocking.
get() function blocks the running thread.
If you are using Java 8 or above , I recommend using completablefuture

Comment: That would not explain the reported timings, @MrNobody.  `terrainsInCreation.add()` is not in the timed region, and `future.get()` is invoked only for futures that report being done.

Comment: Have you checked `DisplayManager.getCurrentTime()`?

Comment: I agree that the behavior seems surprising.  When `future.isDone()` returns true, I expect `future.getResult()` to run without blocking.  I also expect that when there are more tasks than available execution resources (and they take 20-ish milliseconds each), collection of the corresponding futures will be spread out over multiple calls to `checkForFutures()`.  It does indeed appear that despite the first future reporting being done, retrieving its result blocks until all the tasks have finished.

Comment: I don't see an obvious flaw in your approach, though we would need a [mre] to say for sure.  Based on the information presented, I'm inclined to think that your `ExecutorService` is serving you poorly.  You could try switching that out for a different implementation, and you might consider isolating that and testing it on your workload to study the issue (and to be able to test other implementations).

Comment: @akuzminykh `DisplayManager.getCurrentTime()` is this method: `return Sys.getTime()*1000/Sys.getTimerResolution();`

Comment: @ThibaultAbry Then it's either a bug, or you have not shown some important details. I kinda trust the Java-libraries more, so it's gotta be a problem in your code. :(

Comment: @JohnBollinger I isolated the multithreading part in a minimal reproducible example and everything was fine, it turned out that the blocking line is one of the `//Some instructions` just after the `//future.get`  . I'll edit my post and keep investigating, thanks for the idea and the help !

Comment: You should consider using a countdown latch to resume the main thread once terrain generation is complete. Have each future task decrement the latch, and when it hits zero, bam. 

Then you never have to keep track of futures or poll for their state.

Comment: Its not enough information and I need example source, but some ideas: a) Asynchronous interaction between threads works better when using queues to exchange messages (ArrayBlockingQueue). b) OpenGL calls can be made only in the initialized context (thread). Calling OpenGL from different threads can cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @BolatBasheyev I opened an another question because after some researching the problem isn't the ExecutorService but a method of openGL waiting for something. No openGL calls are done in another thread than the main one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862253/lwjgl-glgenvertexarrays-is-blocking-the-execution?